# mysqli array to mysql in subquery?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this select:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select following from following where user =? and block=0");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($followers);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

I'd like to use $followers in another mysql conection:

> select... from ... where (p.user in (**?**))

in this `?` I'd like to place the $followers variable in mysql in format. (1,5,7,2).
Any ideas how to convert the bind_result $followers into this mysql in format?

Comment: Or you could simply combine the two queries using a join. Probably much faster execution and lower server load. But with out real queries to look at, and table schemas, there's no way to give you a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this would be to create another string variable and append the result of `$followers` in a `while` loop.

I typically work in procedural style, and I am assuming that your statement returns multiple rows into `$followers`:

```
$sql_in_string = '';   // initialize string variable as blank
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
    $sql_in_string = $sql_in_string . $followers . "," ; // append value + comma
}
$sql_in_string = rtrim($sql_in_string,",");  // remove the final comma
```

At this point, `$sql_in_string` should have your values as "1,2,3" format and then you can bind that parameter to your next query.